# OnClicklistener not working

Tags: java, android

I load the image programmatically and set onclicklistener but it's not working if I click the image.

```
ImageView ImgBook = new ImageView(this);
    ImgBook.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);       
    ImgBook.setClickable(true);

ImgBook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        //exit code
    }
});
```

How to do this?

Comment: please try first toast message.

Comment: one.this.finish(); where one is the class name,, i tried toast also but its not working

Comment: Try [new View.OnClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) instead of `new OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First figure out if the imageView is registered to listen to onClick events. Put a toast or a Log.d message to find out if the control is going to the onClick method. If you still have issues, refer to the below link.

To set an ImageView programatically, follow this:

[Adding image programmatically to RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10436234/735675)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set View.onClick.... so replace this code

```
    ImgBook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //exit code
        }
    });
```

with below

```
 ImgBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("TEST","in onclick");

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

ImageView ImgBook = new ImageView(this);
ImgBook.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

```
    LinearLayout lyt=new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Params.setMargins(6, 0, 6, 0);

    lyt.addView(ImgBook);
    setContentView(lyt);

    ImgBook.setClickable(true);

    ImgBook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

        }
    });
```